# cd Program Files error: positional parameter cannot be found

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

```
PS C:\> cd Program Files
```

When I give this command, I don't know why, but it is not accepting `Program Files`. The same command is working perfectly fine in `cmd`.

This is the error it shows:

```
Set-Location : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Files'.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd Program Files
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

Comment: `cd 'Program Files'`

Comment: After having typed the first chars hit `[tab]` (repeatedly) to cycle through names starting with those chars. Quotes and `.\` prefix are added automatically as required.

Comment: @Olaf Sometimes, you're running into a stack of problems that aren't very related. Their profile states they're a student and their question shows lack of knowledge of powershell in general. I feel my answer explains the different elements well, but there are 2-3 different issues within this question.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1  I'm used to think that especially the younglings today even more than anything else using google as their first place to ask questions. But I might be wrong with this opinion. ;-)  But I'm pretty sure about that they don't try to figure things out by themselfs. At least that's what I'm used to experiencing with our apprentices. Thanks for your answer anyway. Have a nice Sunday.

Answer (score 28):

**tl;dr**

Since your directory name contains *spaces*, you must *quote* it, e.g.:

```bash
# Note: In PowerShell, 'cd' is an alias of 'Set-Location'
cd 'Program Files'
```

Alternatively, if the intent is to change to the well-known programs folder (typically,
`C:\Program Files`), you may reference the relevant [environment variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Environment_Variables), in which case quoting is *not* required:<sup>[1]</sup>
`cd $env:ProgramFiles` instead of `cd 'C:\Program Files'`

The following discusses how to pass string *literals* with spaces as single arguments.

---

As stated in [Maximilian Burszley's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51459512/45375), `Program Files` is parsed as *two* arguments, because spaces are used to *separate* command-line arguments.

<sup>Your attempt to use `cd Program Files` may be inspired by `cmd.exe` (the legacy Command Prompt), where this syntax indeed works; however, even there it conceptually violates the usual rules of argument parsing.</sup>

Therefore, **you need to use a form of *quoting* in order to pass a value that *contains spaces* as a *single* argument**.

You have several options to implement this quoting:

- Use **`'...'`** *around* values that are *literals*, i.e., that should be used *verbatim*; a `'...'` string is called a [*verbatim* (single-quoted) string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings).
- Use **`"..."`** *around* values in which you want to embed *variable references* (e.g., `$HOME`) or *subexpressions* (e.g., `$(Get-Date)`; that is, `"..."` strings perform *string interpolation*, and they're called [*expandable* (double-quoted) strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings).
- Use **`` ` ``** to quote (escape) a *single* character; `` ` ``, the so-called *backtick*, is PowerShell's general [escape character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters).

Therefore, you could use any of the following:

```bash
cd 'Program Files'
cd "Program Files"  # as there are no $-prefixed tokens, same as 'Program Files'
cd Program` Files   # `-escape just the space char.
```

---

Also, **you can use *tab-completion*** to expand the (space-less) *prefix* of a space-containing path to its full form *with quoting applied implicitly*.

E.g., if you're in `C:\` and you type:

```bash
cd Program<tab>
```

PowerShell automatically completes the command to:

```bash
 cd '.\Program Files\'
```

Note how the `Program Files` (along with `.\` to refer to the current dir. and a trailing `\` to indicate a dir.) was *automatically single-quoted*.

---

**Using *wildcard expressions* as arguments**:

As noted, in PowerShell `cd` is a built-in alias of the **[`Set-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location)** cmdlet.

Passing a path *positionally* - e.g. `Set-Location 'C:\Program Files'` - **implicitly binds it to the `-Path` parameter**; that is it, is equivalent to `Set-Location -Path 'C:\Program Files'`

**`-Path` interprets its argument as a [wildcard expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards)**, so that you can do something like `Set-Location C:\Win*` in order to change to `C:\Windows` (assuming that the wildcard expression matches only *one* directory).

The tricky thing is that - unlike in `cmd.exe` - it isn't just `*` and `?` that have special meaning in PowerShell wildcard expressions, but `[` and `]` as well (for character-set and character-range expressions such as `[abc]` and `[a-c]`), so that `Set-Location Foo[1]` will *not* work for changing to a directory *literally* named `Foo[1]`.

In that case, you must use the **`-LiteralPath` parameter** -

`Set-Location -LiteralPath Foo[1]` - to ensure that the path is **interpreted *literally* (verbatim)**.

---

<sup>[1] This even applies if you append a *space-less* literal, e.g. `cd $env:ProgramFiles\Git`; however, if the literal part contains spaces, quoting is again needed; while, e.g., `cd $env:ProgramFiles\'Common Files'` works, the preferable approach is to enclose the entire argument in `"..."`: `cd "$env:ProgramFiles\Common Files"`</sup>

Answer (score 7):

```
cd C:\Program` Files\
```

> **`** just escape the space in folder name.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is invalid syntax.  Each argument to a powershell command is separated by space, so what you're actually doing is something similar to:

```
Set-Location -Path Program -Arg2 Files
```

But `Set-Location` (aliased: `cd`) does not have any positional arguments for a second position, so it can't bind it to any parameters and use it in the command, hence the terminating error.

---

If you want a simpler `cd` alias, you could do something like this (in your `$profile`):

```
function ChangeDirectory {
    param(
        [Parameter(
            Position = 0,
            Mandatory,
            ValueFromRemainingArguments
        )]
        [string[]] $Path
    )

    Set-Location -Path ($Path -join ' ')
}
Set-Alias -Name cd -Value ChangeDirectory
```

Do note, however, that if you're not specifying a relative path (`.\`), it will use the root path of your current drive (most likely, `C:\`).  This can be tuned in the function to test for both locations (relative and drive-rooted), but logic for figuring out which one to use if they both exist would be tricky (or can always default to relative).

Comment: +1 for the explanation, but I wish you hadn't included the `ValueFromRemainingArguments ` solution, because using arguments this way encourages "fuzzy thinking" - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7190

Comment: @mklement0 I understand that from a technical sense for consistency, but what I suggested is a profile modification to get the functionality desired.  You shouldn't be setting locations in a script anyways.  I'd argue `Write-Host` follows this "fuzzy thinking"

Comment: It's not about `cd` / `Set-Location` in particular, it's about not indulging someone's lack of understanding of command-mode syntax with tricky workarounds that won't work in most other contexts - using `ValueFromRemainingArguments` this way is an ill-advised repurposing.
`Write-Host` is rarely the right tool to begin with; that it can be thought of as obscuring how its arguments are parsed doesn't help; a quick experiment such as `Write-Host 'a b'       c             d` is enough to demonstrate that it too uses regular argument parsing.

Answer (score 2):

**Use quotes (double or single) to go to the folder or path contains white spaces or special symbols.**

Forexample:-

```
cd "C:\Users\LAPTOP0534\OneDrive - My Content (Active Directory)"
```

OR

```
cd 'OneDrive - My Content (Active Directory)\My Folder'
```

**For your case it will be** `PS C:\> cd "Program Files"`

Answer (score 0):

Just run your command prompt as administrator .
See the picture attached.
It will run easily

[image]

Comment: The premise of the question is that everything works as expected in `cmd.exe`, but _not in PowerShell_. Thus, there is no need to address `cmd.exe`'s behavior, and suggesting that _running as an administrator_ is necessary is ill-advised.

Answer (score 0):

[Solving space in path issue with string literal " "](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWXfR.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This is because of the space between the sentences. Enter code here You complete the tab.
Replace PS F: > cd new folder with PS F: > cd "new folder" in the PowerShell. Or look at F: > cd './new folder'. I'm a beginner and you should try this.

Answer (score -1):

You can also launch powershell from explorer writing pwsh over the path and click enter, that open powrshell in speific location, easier.

Comment: How does that solve the described problem?